# How to create django project in cmd

Tags: python, django

I have been unable to create django project via command prompt. Here is the path I set in the environment variable: C:\Users\Freddy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts;C:\Users\Freddy\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django. I tried to run this "django-admin" in command prompt I got this message that "
django-admin is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file" What do I do?

Comment: How did you install django?  Typically the `django-admin` script is installed in a bin directory somewhere, not in the site-packages directory.

Answer (score 2):

As error is clearly saying that django-admin not installed to install it you can you **pip**.
You can use following command for window

- py -m pip install virtualenvwrapper-win
- mkvirtualenv myproject
- workon myproject
- py -m pip install Django

Answer (score 1):

I installed it using pip "pip install django" and it was successfully installed.Also I was able to check the version in the python shell. Here is the path it was automatically installed "AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django"C:\Users\Freddy\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\bin
another folder which contains django-admin "C:\Users\Freddy\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts"

Answer (score 0):

Use below cmds

```
mkdir <filename> && cd <filename>

python -m venv <projectname> && cd <projectname>

scripts\activate

pip install django
django-admin <projectname>
```